# Data Corruption - ERROR: could not open segment 2 of relation

Tags: postgresql, recovery, corruption, postgresql-8.1

I am getting the below error for a production database. I am new to PostgreSQL databases. I need help to get this fixed.

```
2015-10-28 10:25:04,154 [monitor-thread-pool1-thread-6] ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or
directory

server1=>  select oid::regclass from pg_class where relfilenode =98947;
          oid
------------------------
 alert_instance_history
(1 row)

server1=>  select oid::regclass from pg_class where relfilenode =98913;
 oid
-----
(0 rows)

server1=> select * from pg_database where oid=1663;
 datname | datdba | encoding | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datvacuumxid | datfrozenxid | dattablespace | datconfig | datacl
---------+--------+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------
(0 rows)

1. server1=> select version();
                                          version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.1.4 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)
(1 row)
```

1. Error says 2 relations but I can only find 98947. How can I check the other segment ?
2. I just did a select on this table alert_instance_history, I can see records from this table. Do I need to check anything else?

   ```
   server1=> select min(eventtimestamp) from alert_instance_history;

   WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of 1663/98913/98947
   DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error may be permanent.
   ERROR:  could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or directory
   CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation 1663/98913/98947
   server1=>
   server1=> reindex table alert_instance_history;
   WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of 1663/98913/98947
   DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error may be permanent.
   ERROR:  could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or directory
   CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation 1663/98913/98947
   ```
3. What's the possible options I have to restore, Can I restore just one table? 
   Backup of this database is done using pg_dump utility.
4. I verified random tables all of them are producing the same error.

   ```
   cmproddb=> select min(CREATEDATE) from checkpointdata;
   WARNING:  could not write block 427542 of 1663/98913/98947
   DETAIL:  Multiple failures --- write error may be permanent.
   ERROR:  could not open segment 2 of relation 1663/98913/98947 (target block 427542): No such file or directory
   CONTEXT:  writing block 427542 of relation 1663/98913/98947
   ```

Comment: The very first thing you should do when you encounter messages like this is to capture a filesystem copy of the data directory while PostgreSQL is not running and save it somewhere safe. Follow the wiki entry on [Corruption](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption). Once that is safely off of the machine, check for hardware issues.

Comment: By the version string from your PostgreSQL installation (`PostgreSQL 8.1.4 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)`), both the version of your OS and PostgreSQL are *ancient and unsupported*. That version of gcc is from Debian Sarge (3.1), which went EOL in April 2008, and PostgreSQL 8.1 which went EOL in November 2010, so you should definitely consider moving to a supported OS and version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: X-post from http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/119466/7788

Comment: Wow. That's *incredibly* ancient. "Segment 2" refers to the relation extent, like `1663/98913/98947.2`. "No such file or directory" strongly suggests that either accidental admin action deleted them, or you have some bad filesystem corruption. Do you have backups? I hope you have backups. You should look up which relation that is - check `select relname from pg_class where relid = 98947`. Also, if it's index related you *might* be able to recover enough to do a `pg_dump` by starting `postgres` in single-user mode with system indexes disabled. See the manual for the "postgres" command.

Comment: @Kassandry Thanks for posting the corruption link. Too often people try to "fix" things before taking a copy, and it's good to have more people giving the "hands off the keyboard, now take a copy" talk.